# Problem when plotting CI interval using the predict() function

Tags: r, plot, intervals, predict

I am trying to plot the result of my linear model with the 95% confidence interval as follows:

```
fem:
+---------------------+------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
|       "Sitio"       |   "Zona"   |       "ID"        | "Wg_g" |       "GSI"       |        "K"         |      "Klog"       |       "Wglog"       |      "GSIlog"      |
+---------------------+------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| "Tablas de Daimiel" | "Tablazo"  | "L. gibbosus -27" |  2.692 |  9.15646258503401 | 0.0261364929449249 | -1.58275268748418 |   0.430075055551939 |  0.961727725139782 |
| "Tablas de Daimiel" | "Tablazo"  | "L. gibbosus -29" |  1.162 |  6.24731182795699 | 0.0255144032921811 | -1.59321458410006 |  0.0652061280543119 |  0.795693183836396 |
| "Tablas de Daimiel" | "Tablazo"  | "L. gibbosus -30" |  2.669 |  12.0769230769231 | 0.0257763522379356 | -1.58877854218143 |   0.426348573787508 |    1.0819563001024 |
| "Tablas de Daimiel" | "Tablazo"  | "L. gibbosus -32" |  2.104 |  8.99145299145299 | 0.0248620897755187 | -1.60446236966734 |   0.323045735481701 |  0.953829878071559 |
| "Tablas de Daimiel" | "Tablazo"  | "L. gibbosus -33" |   2.52 |  10.9565217391304 | 0.0259964554398148 | -1.58508586310111 |   0.401400540781544 |   1.03967270476395 |
| "Tablas de Daimiel" | "Tablazo"  | "L. gibbosus -34" |  1.434 |  5.64566929133858 | 0.0278303401108612 |  -1.5554814861788 |   0.156549151331781 |  0.751715434711843 |
| "Tablas de Daimiel" | "Tablazo"  | "L. gibbosus -36" |  0.253 |  1.28426395939086 | 0.0244916125551217 | -1.61098261950021 |  -0.596879478824182 |  0.108654295014225 |
| "Tablas de Daimiel" | "Tablazo"  | "L. gibbosus -38" |  0.302 |   1.5978835978836 | 0.0259259259259259 | -1.58626572414473 |  -0.519993057042849 |  0.203545138783906 |
| "Tablas de Daimiel" | "Tablazo"  | "L. gibbosus -39" |  4.357 |   12.342776203966 | 0.0272580768461556 | -1.56450478843405 |   0.639187559935754 |   1.09141285454793 |
| "Tablas de Daimiel" | "Tablazo"  | "L. gibbosus -40" |  2.276 |  8.75384615384615 |              0.026 | -1.58502665202918 |   0.357172257723034 |  0.942198909752216 |
| "Tablas de Daimiel" | "Tablazo"  | "L. gibbosus -41" |  3.358 |  11.2307692307692 | 0.0244073065190365 |  -1.6124801447312 |    0.52608069180203 |    1.0504095034776 |
| "Las Madres"        | "Butrones" | "L.gibbosus -05"  |  0.027 | 0.673316708229426 | 0.0176666769465286 | -1.75284513241212 |   -1.56863623584101 | -0.171780608461195 |
| "Las Madres"        | "Butrones" | "L.gibbosus -10"  |   0.03 | 0.761421319796954 | 0.0157570376769167 | -1.80252542653517 |   -1.52287874528034 | -0.118374967105912 |
| "Las Madres"        | "Butrones" | "L.gibbosus -21"  |  0.183 |  1.04214123006834 | 0.0192401878876662 | -1.71579069122865 |  -0.737548910269571 | 0.0179265781603458 |
| "Las Madres"        | "Butrones" | "L.gibbosus -23"  |  1.143 |  5.94383775351014 | 0.0224289254993439 | -1.64919153162806 |  0.0580462303952817 |  0.774066946156802 |
| "Las Madres"        | "Butrones" | "L.gibbosus -25"  |  0.793 |  5.98490566037736 | 0.0194432052967693 | -1.71123213817768 |  -0.100726812682396 |  0.777057309044777 |
| "Las Madres"        | "Butrones" | "L.gibbosus -26"  |  0.989 |  3.81853281853282 | 0.0153694695871428 | -1.81334112009634 | -0.0048037084028206 |  0.581896527515928 |
| "Las Madres"        | "Butrones" | "L.gibbosus -27"  |  0.069 | 0.745945945945946 | 0.0187611933335902 | -1.72673954113229 |   -1.16115090926274 | -0.127292642001777 |
+---------------------+------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------------+


lm1 <- lm(Wglog ~ Klog, data = fem)

newx <- seq(min(fem$Klog),max(fem$Klog),length.out = length(fem$Klog))
pred1 <- predict(lm1, new=data.frame(x=newx),level=.95,interval="confidence")
```

But the predicted values don´t make sense, as they are completely erratic and somehow disordered:

```
plot(fem$Wglog ~ fem$Klog, 
     ylab = "Log gonad weight",
     xlab = "",
     xaxt = "n",
     ylim = c(-3,3),
     pch = c(4,20),
     font.lab = 2)
abline(lm1, col = "grey", lwd = 2) #a straight line with the actual coefficients of the model
lines(x = newx, y = as.vector(pred1$fit[,1]), col="blue", lty=2, lwd = 2) #this line, if I didn´t get it wrong, should be the same as the abline
lines(x = newx, y = as.vector(pred1$fit[,2]), col="black", lty=2, lwd = 2) #these represent the confidence interval
lines(x = newx, y = as.vector(pred1$fit[,3]), col="black", lty=2, lwd = 2)
```

[you can check the resulting plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB7RC.png)

If I sort the predicted values they make more sense, but they seem to be wrong anyways:

```
lines(x = newx, y = sort(as.vector(pred1$fit[,1])), col="blue", lty=2, lwd = 2)
lines(x = newx, y = sort(as.vector(pred1$fit[,2])), col="black", lty=2, lwd = 2)
lines(x = newx, y = sort(as.vector(pred1$fit[,3])), col="black", lty=2, lwd = 2)
```

[and the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRhCU.png)

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
pred1 <- predict(lm1, new=data.frame(x=newx),level=.95,interval="confidence")
```

should be

```
pred1 <- predict(lm1, new=data.frame(Klog=newx),level=.95,interval="confidence")`
```

Because you're providing a new data frame that doesn't have the same variables as are in the model (i.e., it doesn't have a variable named `Klog`) you're just getting the predictions from the original model. Also, the result of the `predict()` function is a matrix not a list or data frame.  Below is code that works:

```
fem <- tibble::tribble(
  ~"Klog"       ,       ~"Wglog"       ,
 -1.58275268748418 ,   0.430075055551939 ,
 -1.59321458410006 ,  0.0652061280543119 ,
 -1.58877854218143 ,   0.426348573787508 ,
 -1.60446236966734 ,   0.323045735481701 ,
 -1.58508586310111 ,   0.401400540781544 ,
  -1.5554814861788 ,   0.156549151331781 ,
 -1.61098261950021 ,  -0.596879478824182 ,
 -1.58626572414473 ,  -0.519993057042849 ,
 -1.56450478843405 ,   0.639187559935754 ,
 -1.58502665202918 ,   0.357172257723034 ,
  -1.6124801447312 ,    0.52608069180203 ,
 -1.75284513241212 ,   -1.56863623584101 ,
 -1.80252542653517 ,   -1.52287874528034 ,
 -1.71579069122865 ,  -0.737548910269571 ,
 -1.64919153162806 ,  0.0580462303952817 ,
 -1.71123213817768 ,  -0.100726812682396 ,
 -1.81334112009634 , -0.0048037084028206 ,
 -1.72673954113229 ,   -1.16115090926274 )

lm1 <- lm(Wglog ~ Klog, data = fem)

newx <- seq(min(fem$Klog),max(fem$Klog),length.out = length(fem$Klog))
pred1 <- predict(lm1, new=data.frame(Klog=newx),level=.95,interval="confidence")

plot(fem$Wglog ~ fem$Klog, 
     ylab = "Log gonad weight",
     xlab = "",
     xaxt = "n",
     ylim = c(-3,3),
     pch = c(4,20),
     font.lab = 2)
abline(lm1, col = "grey", lwd = 2) #a straight line with the actual coefficients of the model
lines(x = newx, y = pred1[,1], col="blue", lty=2, lwd = 2) #this line, if I didn´t get it wrong, should be the same as the abline
lines(x = newx, y = pred1[,2], col="black", lty=2, lwd = 2) #these represent the confidence interval
lines(x = newx, y = pred1[,3], col="black", lty=2, lwd = 2)
```

[image]